# Java Swing: Can't see components of class that extends JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, extends

I create this class JPanelCaso that extends JPanel:

```
public class JPanelCaso extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    JCheckBox checkBox;
    JTextArea textArea;
    String frasePerCliente = "";
    private int distanzaDaBordi = 0;
    private int distanzaCheckTextA = 5;
    private SpringLayout layoutPnlCaso = new SpringLayout();

    /**
     * Costruttore della classe Caso
     * 
     * @param checkBox l' oggetto di tipo JCheckBox relativo al caso
     * @param textArea l' oggetto di tipo JtextArea relativo al caso
     */
    JPanelCaso(String strTitoloCaso, String frasePerCliente){
        this.addMouseListener(this);

        checkBox = new JCheckBox();
        checkBox.addMouseListener(this);

        textArea = new JTextArea(strTitoloCaso);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.addMouseListener(this);
        textArea.setEditable(false);

        this.frasePerCliente = frasePerCliente;

        componiPannello();

    }

    private void componiPannello() {
        this.setLayout(layoutPnlCaso);

        //Dispongo i controlli
        layoutPnlCaso.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, checkBox, distanzaDaBordi, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
        layoutPnlCaso.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, checkBox, -distanzaCheckTextA, SpringLayout.WEST, textArea);
        layoutPnlCaso.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, textArea, -distanzaDaBordi, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
        layoutPnlCaso.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, checkBox, distanzaDaBordi, SpringLayout.NORTH, this);
        layoutPnlCaso.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, textArea, distanzaDaBordi, SpringLayout.NORTH, this);
        layoutPnlCaso.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, textArea, distanzaDaBordi, SpringLayout.SOUTH, this);

        this.add(checkBox);
        this.add(textArea);

    }
}
```

Than i'm inserting various JPanelCaso in a JPanel that is a card of another JPanel with cards Layout:

```
public class GuidaBpoEse{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GuidaBpoEse();
            }
        }); 
    }

    public GuidaBpoEse() {      
        creaFinestraMain();
    }


    Workbook wbDbCommentiEse = null;
    Dimension grandezzaSchermo = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int larghezzaMain = (int)(grandezzaSchermo.getWidth() * 0.20);
    int altezzaMain = (int)(grandezzaSchermo.getHeight() * 0.95);
    Point inizioMain = new Point((int)grandezzaSchermo.getWidth() - larghezzaMain, 0);
    JFrame frmMain = new JFrame();

    int nFogli;
    int iFoglio = 0;
    int righe;  //conta le righe del iFoglio fino all' ultima piena
    int colonne;    //conta le colonne del iFoglio fino all' ultima piena
    int riga;
    int colonna;

    int distanzaTraCasi = 5;
    int distanzaDaBordi = 0;

    static JTextArea txtaFrasiTrovate;

    private void creaFinestraMain() {
        try {
            wbDbCommentiEse = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("db.xls"));
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        nFogli = wbDbCommentiEse.getNumberOfSheets();

        ...

        SpringLayout layoutMain = new SpringLayout();
        JPanel pnlMain = new JPanel(layoutMain);

        ...

            // Pannello della scelta delle macrocasistiche ==================================================

            JPanel pnlMacrocasistiche = new JPanel(new GridLayout(nFogli - 2, 1));
            JScrollPane spnlMacrocasistiche = null;
            JButton[] btnMacrocasistiche = new JButton[nFogli]; //Salterò il primo elemento per far corrispondere l' indice dei fogli nel file excel con l' indice dei fogli nell' array di tasti
            Sheet sAppoggio;
            iFoglio++;
            while (iFoglio < nFogli - 1) {
                iFoglio++;
                sAppoggio = wbDbCommentiEse.getSheet(iFoglio);
                btnMacrocasistiche[iFoglio] = new JButton(sAppoggio.getName());
                pnlMacrocasistiche.add(btnMacrocasistiche[iFoglio]);
                btnMacrocasistiche[iFoglio].addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                        JButton btnAppoggio = (JButton)arg0.getSource();
                        layoutPnlDettagli.show(pnlDettagli, btnAppoggio.getText());
                        frmDettagli.setVisible(true);
                    }

                    ...

                });
            }
            spnlMacrocasistiche = new JScrollPane(pnlMacrocasistiche);
            spnlMacrocasistiche.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Macrocasistiche"));
            pnlMain.add(spnlMacrocasistiche);
            // ==============================================================================================



            //Posiziono spnlMacrocasistiche
            spnlMacrocasistiche.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)frmMain.getWidth(), (int)(frmMain.getHeight() * 0.4)));;
            layoutMain.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, spnlMacrocasistiche, distanzaDaBordi, SpringLayout.SOUTH, pnlDatiCliente);
            layoutMain.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, spnlMacrocasistiche, distanzaDaBordi, SpringLayout.WEST, pnlMain);
            layoutMain.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, spnlMacrocasistiche, -distanzaDaBordi, SpringLayout.EAST, pnlMain);

        frmMain.add(pnlMain);
        creaFinestraDettagliCasistiche();

        frmMain.validate();
        //frmMain.pack();
        frmMain.setVisible(true);
        frmMain.setAlwaysOnTop(true);


    }


    JFrame frmDettagli;
    JPanel pnlDettagli;
    JScrollPane spnlDettagli;
    CardLayout layoutPnlDettagli = new CardLayout();
    SpringLayout layoutPnlCasistiche = new SpringLayout();

    private void creaFinestraDettagliCasistiche() {
        int larghezzaFrmDettagli = (int)(grandezzaSchermo.getWidth() * 0.15);
        int altezzaFrmDettagli = altezzaMain;
        frmDettagli = new JFrame();
        frmDettagli.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frmDettagli.setTitle("Controllo documenti ESE");
        frmDettagli.setSize(larghezzaFrmDettagli, altezzaFrmDettagli);
        Point inizioFrmDettagli = new Point((int)(inizioMain.getX() - frmDettagli.getWidth()), (int)(inizioMain.getY()));
        frmDettagli.setLocation(inizioFrmDettagli);


            pnlDettagli = new JPanel(layoutPnlDettagli);
            Dimension dimMinPnlDettagli = new Dimension((int)(frmDettagli.getWidth()), (int)frmDettagli.getHeight());
            pnlDettagli.setPreferredSize(dimMinPnlDettagli);

            iFoglio = 1;
            Sheet sAppoggio;
            JPanel[] pnlCasistiche = new JPanel[nFogli];
            JPanelCaso[] pnlCaso;

            while (iFoglio < nFogli - 1) {
                iFoglio++;
                sAppoggio = wbDbCommentiEse.getSheet(iFoglio);
                righe = sAppoggio.getRows();
                colonne = sAppoggio.getColumns();
                riga = 0;
                colonna = 0;

                pnlCasistiche[iFoglio] = new JPanel(layoutPnlCasistiche);
                pnlCasistiche[iFoglio].setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(sAppoggio.getName()));
                    pnlCaso = new JPanelCaso[righe];
                    while (riga < righe) {
                        pnlCaso[riga] = new JPanelCaso(sAppoggio.getCell(colonna, riga).getContents(), sAppoggio.getCell(colonna + 1, riga).getContents());


                        //pnlCasistiche[iFoglio].add(new JLabel("Prova"));

                        pnlCasistiche[iFoglio].setSize(frmDettagli.getSize());
                        if (riga == 0) {
                            layoutPnlCasistiche.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, pnlCaso[riga], distanzaDaBordi, SpringLayout.NORTH, pnlCasistiche[iFoglio]);
                            layoutPnlCasistiche.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, pnlCaso[riga], distanzaDaBordi, SpringLayout.WEST, pnlCasistiche[iFoglio]);
                            layoutPnlCasistiche.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, pnlCaso[riga], distanzaDaBordi, SpringLayout.EAST, pnlCasistiche[iFoglio]);
                        } else {
                            layoutPnlCasistiche.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, pnlCaso[riga], distanzaTraCasi, SpringLayout.SOUTH, pnlCaso[riga - 1]);
                            layoutPnlCasistiche.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, pnlCaso[riga], distanzaDaBordi, SpringLayout.WEST, pnlCasistiche[iFoglio]);
                            layoutPnlCasistiche.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, pnlCaso[riga], distanzaDaBordi, SpringLayout.EAST, pnlCasistiche[iFoglio]);
                        }
                        pnlCasistiche[iFoglio].add(pnlCaso[riga]);
                        riga++;
                    }

                    pnlDettagli.add(pnlCasistiche[iFoglio], sAppoggio.getName());


            }

            pnlDettagli.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

                ...

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    frmDettagli.dispose();

                }

                ...

            });

            frmDettagli.add(pnlDettagli);
            frmDettagli.validate();
    }

}
```

The cards of pnlDettagli are showed and i can see the border but i can't see the contents, the various pnlCaso[riga];

I can't figure out why. I set Spring Layout before add components and the xls file is full of data

Many thanks to who answer and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Please create a [mcve], emphasis on **minimal**.

Comment: @DarkV1 *"We only need the parts.."* ..that constitute an MCVE. Posting an MCVE guarantees that the parts that are needed to show the problem, are included in the (stripped down) code.

Comment: Sorry for my bad practice. I think my problem is in the class that extends JPanel..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've resolved.... I just needed to set preferred size for my JPanelCaso.......

Thanks to all, primarly camickr for the support

Comment: (1-) That is not the proper solution. It is the job of the layout manager to return the preferred size of the panel. If the layout manager is NOT doing this then you are not using the layout manager properly. Either don't use the SpringLayout or use the SpringLayout properly. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) for proper working examples. Note the tutorial will also show how to better structure your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
    frmMain.add(pnlMain);
    //frmMain.pack();
    frmMain.setVisible(true);
    frmMain.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    creaFinestraDettagliCasistiche();
```

All components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible. So the code should be:

```
    frmMain.add(pnlMain);
    creaFinestraDettagliCasistiche();
    frmMain.pack();
    frmMain.setVisible(true);
    frmMain.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

If that doesn't solve the problem, then I would say the problem is with your SpringLayout code. That layout is typically only used by an IDE since specifying the constraints correctly can be difficult. I suggest you try another layout manager (or combination of layout managers).

Comment: @FrancescoPiccolomini, what didn't work? Did you change the code to use a better layout manager?

Comment: I refer to put creaFinestraDettagliCasistiche(); before frmMain.setVisible(true);

When i've added single check box and textarea, it worked. I think i should use object Caso that contain checkBox and textArea and assemble them in the main class calling them from the Caso object.

I'll try and feedback you

Comment: `When i've added single check box and textarea, it worked.` - right. And that is why I suggested the problem is the layout manager you are using on the panel. If you don't set the constraints properly then the layout won't work. Try just comments out all the layout code for the SpringLayout and just use the default FlowLayout. That is an easy way to verify if the SpringLayout is the problem.